# Catch error outside callback of puppeteers listener page.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, puppeteer

I am occurring the following problem while implementing an end-to-end test with puppeteer.

I try to catch the thrown error outside the page listener. Unfortunately it is not accessable outside the callback of the page.on (puppeteer) listener.

```
(async () => {
  try {   
// http error handling
    page.on('response', response => {
      if (!response.ok() && response.request().resourceType() === 'xhr')
        throw new Error('HTTP Error occurred');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // want to catch error here
    console.log('error while running end-2-end test');
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

I only log `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with asynchronous code. Although your code looks like the exception is thrown inside the try-catch block, the function you are giving to the `page.on` function is run later and therefore any error thrown inside is not caught.

Therefore, you have to move the try-catch block into the function (in case the `throw new Error` is just example code). You can still call a function in the outer scope from inside the catch block if you want to. Alternatively, you could just remove the `throw` statement and call the `handleError` function directly.

```js
function handleError(err) {
    // handle the error
}

page.on('response', response => {
    try {
        if (!response.ok() && response.request().resourceType() === 'xhr') {
            throw new Error('HTTP Error occurred');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using EventEmitter

You can create an instance on eventEmitter that will listen to some error or custom event.

```
// create your own error catching event
const events = require('events');
const catchErrors = new events.EventEmitter();
catchErrors.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
```

Later on,

```
page.on('response', response => {
      if (!response.ok() && response.request().resourceType() === 'xhr')
        catchErrors.emit('error', new Error('HTTP Error occurred'));
});
```

## Catch all errors

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  console.log('unhandledRejection', error.message);
});
```